# Toggle boolean in MySQL / Oracle Database

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
Update myTable SET field = 1 (if field = 0 or if field is null) where myid = 12345;
Update myTable SET field = 0 (if field = 1) where myid = 12345;
```

What is the best way to transform this Pseudocode in proper SQL for Oracle and MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use the modulo like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET field = (field + 1) % 2 WHERE myId = 12345;
```

Comment: It should be modulo 2. Modulo 1 always results in a 0 in your example

Answer (score 3):

Due to the lack of a *real* boolean in both DBMS you need a case statement:

```
update myTable
   set the_column = case when the_column = 1 then 0 else 1 end
where myId = 12345;
```

This assumes that the column never has different values than 0 and 1